# Need to show the text from the list using child nodes

Tags: javascript, html

```js
  function seeListItems() {
    var olElement = document.getElementById("toDoList");
    var st = "";

    for (var i=0; i < olElement.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if(olElement.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
         st += olElement.childNodes[i].nodeValue;
        }
    }
    alert(st);

    var pElement = document.getElementById("toDoNotes");
    var str = "";

    for (var j=0; j < pElement.childNodes.length; j++) {
        if(pElement.childNodes[j].nodeType == 3) {
            str += pElement.childNodes[j].nodeValue;
        }
    }
    alert(str);
}
```

```html
<h1>Things To Do</h1>
<ol id="toDoList">
    <li>Mow the lawn</li>
    <li>Clean the windows</li>
    <li>Answer your email</li>
</ol>

<p id="toDoNotes">Make sure all tasks are done by 10pm.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="seeListItems();">Run function</button>
```

Need to show the text (all three lines) from the list using child nodes.
it works with toDoNotes, but does not with toDoList, tried to change nodeValue to nodeName and it did not change anything. also played with node type and still no changes, when executing the code first alert is blank and the second works properly

Comment: There is a typo there: `oielement` and `olelement`. You typed "i" instead of "l".

Comment: I corrected it, problem still there)

Comment: first alert shows nullnullnull with nodeType=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the `childNode[0]`  of any `element` is a `textNode` so you could start from the `childNode[1]`. Similarly all even `childNodes` will be `textNodes` so you have to print the value of odd `childNodes` of `#toDoList` as follows;

```js
function seeListItems() {
    var oiElement = document.getElementById("toDoList");
    var st = "";
    for (var i = 1; i < oiElement.childNodes.length; i=i+2) {
        if (oiElement.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeType == 3) {
            st = st + oiElement.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "\n";
        } 
    }
    alert(st);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <script src="to.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Things To Do</h1>
    <ol id="toDoList">
        <li>Mow the lawn</li>
        <li>Clean the windows</li>
        <li>Answer your email</li>
    </ol>
    <button onclick="seeListItems()">
        Show works
    </button>
```

See the image for more clarification;

[image]

Comment: what is the function of childNodes[0] and its difference with childNodes[i]?

Comment: `childode[0]` is actually `textNode` of `<li>` like textNode[0] of `#toDoList` is a `textNode`

Answer (score 0):

You can use that :

```
function seeListItems() {
    var olElements = document.querySelectorAll("#toDoList li");

    olElements.forEach(function(li){
      alert(li.innerText);
    })

    var pElement = document.getElementById("toDoNotes");
    var str = "";

    for (var j=0; j < pElement.childNodes.length; j++) {
        if(pElement.childNodes[j].nodeType == 1) {
          str += pElement.childNodes[j].nodeValue;
        }
    }
    alert(str);
}
```

EDIT : Simplification =>

```
<script>
function seeListItems() {
    document.querySelectorAll("#toDoList li").forEach(function(li){
      alert(li.innerText);
    })

    alert(document.getElementById("toDoNotes").innerText);
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, but I need to use almost the same method that is used with the second id which is "toDoNotes"

Comment: Which part of it you want to use specifically?

Comment: I need to obtain an alert that will show all 3 sentences from the list. I have to use node (we are on the dom chapter) but I don't understand where is the mistake

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the script `olElement` is not defined anywhere.

```js
function seeListItems() {
  var oiElement = document.getElementById("toDoList");
  var st = "";


  for (var i = 0; i < oiElement.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (oiElement.childNodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
      st += oiElement.childNodes[i].nodeValue;
    }
  }
  alert(st);

  var pElement = document.getElementById("toDoNotes");
  var str = "";

  for (var j = 0; j < pElement.childNodes.length; j++) {
    if (pElement.childNodes[j].nodeType == 1) {
      str += pElement.childNodes[j].nodeValue;
    }
  }
  alert(str);
}
```

```html
<h1>Things To Do</h1>
<ol id="toDoList">
  <li>Mow the lawn</li>
  <li>Clean the windows</li>
  <li>Answer your email</li>
</ol>

<p id="toDoNotes">Make sure all tasks are done by 10pm.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="seeListItems();">Run function</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code. `var oiElement = document.getElementById("toDoList");` should be `var olElement = document.getElementById("toDoList");`.

Also, have you considered using jQuery. I think it would greatly simplify what you're trying to do. Some people bash jQuery because of it's size, but I don't think it's that bad. Not too bad when you consider how many lines of code you'll save!

Consider this example:

```js
function seeListItems()
{
  $("#toDoList").children('li').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>To-Do List</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Things To Do</h1>
<ol id="toDoList">
        <li>Mow the lawn</li>
        <li>Clean the windows</li>
        <li>Answer your email</li>
    </ol>

<p id="toDoNotes">Make sure all tasks are done by 10pm.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="seeListItems();">Run function</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot use query, my task is to get the alert with the node.value

Answer (score 0):

I just made the following changes for clarity:

```
function seeListItems() {
var oiElement = document.getElementById("toDoList");
var st = "";

for (var i=0; i < oiElement.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if(oiElement.childNodes[i].nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      st += oiElement.childNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
    }
}

alert(st);

var pElement = document.getElementById("toDoNotes");
var str = "";

for (var j=0; j < pElement.childNodes.length; j++) {
    if(pElement.childNodes[j].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      str += pElement.childNodes[j].nodeValue;
    }
}
alert(str);
```

}

You also mispelt oiElement as olElement.